# Suppose that $x_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.Is it true that, if $x_n < M$ for all $n$, then we must have $x<M$ also?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I've been given this question as part of a set of practice questions for my university real-analysis course and I just can't figure out a way to prove it.

So far what I've figured out is the question seems to hinge on the idea that, for all $n$, $x_n \leq x$ or $x_n <x$. If this is the case and tips on how I could prove this would be very much appreciated!

I cant seem to find a counter example as it seems that the only counter example can be one in which $x_n < x$ which also hinges on proving $x_n \leq x$ or $x_n < x$.

I apologise if any of my logic is a bit strange I'm new to all this. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Actually it should be $x\leq M$ beacause think of in $\lbrace 1-\frac{1}{n}\rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded by $M=1$ and its limit is $1$. 

A proof for that is by contradiction, suppose $x>M$ then $x-M$ is a positive number so for some natural number $N$ you should have $|x-x_{N}|<x-M$, that means you've found an element from the sequence greater than $M$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False. $-1/n < 0$ for all $n \geq 1$ but $\lim_n (-1/n) = 0$.

In general, limits preserve $\leq$ but not $<$.